# Calculating memory usage in R Shiny Application

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to decrease the amount of memory used in a R Shiny application to allow for more calculation and usage. In calculating the memory used from pryr package in server.R, my printout is showing 148-149 MB are used even before any rendering is completed.

```
server.R

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
print("before loading packages")
print(pryr::mem_used())
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
require(class)
library(data.table)
```

I have inserted print statements all throughout my server.R but am unable to find where the initial 148-149 memory usage is coming from. Any help would be appreciated.